# How i send list like parameter with restangular post?

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I have this code:

```
postAssignUserToProject(pid: number, selectedUsers: any, uid: number) {
    var me = this;
    return me.Restangular.all("configure/assign").one(pid.toString()).one(uid.toString()).post(selectedUsers);
}
```

Comment: selectedUsers: Is a list of id's... And dont work. What i miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should put them into an object,and use Restangular

```
obj = {
 pid: pid.toString()
 selectedUsers: selectedUsers
 uid: uid.toString()
}
Restangular.one(url).post(obj).then(function(res){
  // do something
})
```

or

```
Restangular.one(url).post({
  pid: pid.toString()
  selectedUsers: selectedUsers
  uid: uid.toString()
}).then(function(res){
  // do something
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This code dont work becouse my backhand service dont recerve this format. 
Example ,y backhand code is:

Comment: [HttpPost]
[Route("assign/{pid}/{changedBy}")]
public HttpResponseMessage AssignUserToProject(int pid, List<int> uid, 
int changedBy)